# SQL query to get min, max rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, select-query, presto

I have following sample data, I want to get min and max time of every consecutive status.

```
cat     subcat  status  logtime
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:00
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:03
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:12
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:15
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:18
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:21
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:24
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:27
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:30
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:33
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:36
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:45
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:48
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:51
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:54
fruits  apple   0   30-10-2017 06:57
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:00
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:03
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  strawberry  2   30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:12
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:15
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:18
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:21
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:24
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:27
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:30
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:33
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:36
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  strawberry  2   30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:45
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:48
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:51
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:54
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:57
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:00
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:03
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  blueberry   2   30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:12
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:15
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:18
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:21
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:24
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:27
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:30
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:33
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:36
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  blueberry   2   30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:45
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:48
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:51
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:54
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:57
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:00
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:03
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  guaua   2   30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:12
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:15
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:18
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:21
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:24
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:27
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:30
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:33
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:36
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  guaua   2   30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:45
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:48
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:51
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:54
fruits  guaua   1   30-10-2017 06:57
```

I'm trying get min, max time of each status for cat and subcat status.

Output result should be following:

```
cat     subcat      status  mintime maxtime
fruits  apple       0   30-10-2017 06:00    30-10-2017 06:57
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:00    30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  strawberry  2   30-10-2017 06:09    30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:12    30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  strawberry  2   30-10-2017 06:42    30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  strawberry  1   30-10-2017 06:45    30-10-2017 06:57
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:00    30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  blueberry   2   30-10-2017 06:09    30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:12    30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  blueberry   2   30-10-2017 06:42    30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  blueberry   0   30-10-2017 06:45    30-10-2017 06:57
fruits  guaua       1   30-10-2017 06:00    30-10-2017 06:06
fruits  guaua       2   30-10-2017 06:09    30-10-2017 06:09
fruits  guaua       1   30-10-2017 06:12    30-10-2017 06:39
fruits  guaua       2   30-10-2017 06:42    30-10-2017 06:42
fruits  guaua       1   30-10-2017 06:45    30-10-2017 06:57
```

tried with following sql query but unable to get above output instead its giving min, max total hour.

```
SELECT cat,
        subcat,
        status,        
        min(logtime) as minlog,
        max(logtime) as maxlog
FROM fruits_log
WHERE 
    cat = 'fruits'
    AND date_format(logtime,'%Y-%m-%d %H) = '2017-10-30 06'
    AND status IN ('0','1','2')
GROUP BY cat,subcat,date_format(logtime,'%Y-%m-%d %H),status
ORDER BY cat,subcat,minlog ;
```

Please help what i'm missing in above query

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: why you have mintime higher then maxtime in the last row? Is the problem considering the ordering according to the `logtime`?

Comment: which version of mysql are you using? are you above 8?

Comment: @RadimBača : updated sample data,i'm using mysql 5.6

Comment: @Strawberry : CREATE TABLE `fruits_log` (
 `cat` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `subcat` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `logtime` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

Comment: The linked answer is, I think, self-explanatory; despite some dissent, 127 people seem to agree with me. Note also that an edit button is provided.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this

```
select  t.cat, t.subcat, t.status, min(t.logdate), max(t.logdate)
from
(
    select t1.cat, t1.subcat, t1.status, t1.logdate, count(t2.cat) grpnum
    from data t1
    left join data t2 on t1.cat = t2.cat and t1.subcat = t2.subcat and 
                         t1.status != t2.status and 
                         t1.logdate < t2.logdate
    group by t1.cat, t1.subcat, t1.status, t1.logdate
) t
group by t.cat, t.subcat, t.status, t.grpnum
```

I have tested on just very small [sample](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b3365dcb2e08bb1ff419524d0da77eab) of your data, but it seems to be ok. The inner query use a self-join to isolate consecutive rows with the same `cat`, `subcat` and `status` values. Once this is ready, you can simply do a `group by` for each group of rows in the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cat,subcat,minlog,maxlog from ( SELECT cat,
            subcat,
            status,        
            min(logtime) as minlog,
            max(logtime) as maxlog
    FROM fruits_log
    WHERE 
        cat = 'fruits'
        AND date_format(logtime,'%Y-%m-%d %H') = '2017-10-30 06'
        AND status IN ('0','1','2')
    GROUP BY cat,subcat,date_format(logtime,"%Y-%m-%d %H-%i"),status) t1 order by cat,subcat,status;
```

try this...

Comment: try the updated one, if not work then provide the result for this query.

Comment: Just a side note, sometimes better to do two single queries one for min and one for max and join them for a quicker execution. But this would only apply if no where clause, and there being and index on the column being aggregated

Comment: @Ab if we putt them in a single query what the difference you get please explain.

Comment: If doing two aggregations on an indexed column, I have seen the query not use index, but all depends on how selective the where clause is. Try on a million row table, with an index on columnA, and doing a min and max in same query as opposed to doing separately and cross joining the two results

Comment: @addy : im getting following output ,       
cat;subcat;status;minlog;maxlog
fruits;apple;0;2017-10-30 06:00:00;2017-10-30 06:57:00
fruits;blueberry;0;2017-10-30 06:00:00;2017-10-30 06:57:00
fruits;blueberry;2;2017-10-30 06:09:00;2017-10-30 06:42:00
fruits;guaua;1;2017-10-30 06:00:00;2017-10-30 06:57:00
fruits;guaua;2;2017-10-30 06:09:00;2017-10-30 06:42:00
fruits;strawberry;1;2017-10-30 06:00:00;2017-10-30 06:57:00
fruits;strawberry;2;2017-10-30 06:09:00;2017-10-30 06:42:00