# Find the start and end date of stock difference

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

Please Suggest good sql query to find the start and end date of stock difference

imagine i data in a table like below.

Sample_table

```
transaction_date  stock
2018-12-01          10
2018-12-02          10
2018-12-03          20
2018-12-04          20
2018-12-05          20
2018-12-06          20
2018-12-07          20
2018-12-08          10
2018-12-09          10
2018-12-10          30
```

Expected result should be

```
Start_date     end_date      stock
2018-12-01     2018-12-02     10
2018-12-03     2018-12-07     20
2018-12-08     2018-12-09     10
2018-12-10     null           30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below using `row_number()`

```
select stock,min(transaction_date) as start_date,
case when min(transaction_date)=max(transaction_date) then null else max(transaction_date) end as end_date
from
(
select *,row_number() over(order by transaction_date)-
row_number() over(partition by stock order by transaction_date) as rn
from t1
)A group by stock,rn
```

Comment: Just a small note: your solution will place a null value into the last column always when you have just one row in the consecutive group: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e69256c5cea06ffa8d9f9c5aace018e

Answer (score 5):

It is the gap and island problem. You may use row_numer and group by for this.

```
select  t.stock, min(transaction_date), max(transaction_date)
from (
   select row_number() over (order by transaction_date) -
      row_number() over (partition by stock order by transaction_date) grp,
      transaction_date,
      stock
   from data
) t
group by t.grp, t.stock
```

In the following [DBFIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3319e47da927da8081d9f762775c1d4f) I solve also the `null` value of the last group, but the main idea of finding consecutive rows is build on the above query.

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669058/postgresql-table-same-data-last-adjacent-occurance-and-first-in-one-row/47669482#47669482) for an explanation of this solution.

Comment: interesting already this answer is given fa06 4minutes before of you

Comment: true, it is a common solution for this problem

Comment: Baca WOW then i think i should have also make it a copy and paste what do you think ?

Comment: Appreciated @RadimBača

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin you can if you want to, but it is not my style ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT
  stock,
  MIN(transaction_date) Start_date,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>1 THEN MAX(transaction_date) END end_date      
FROM Sample_table
GROUP BY stock
ORDER BY stock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with LEAD, LAG functions as below:

```
select currentStockDate as startDate, 
LEAD(currentStockDate,1) as EndDate,
currentStock
from
(select *
from
(select 
LAG(transaction_date,1) over(order by transaction_date) as prevStockDate,
 transaction_date as CurrentstockDate,
LAG(stock,1) over(order by transaction_date) as prevStock,
stock as currentStock
from sample_table) as t
where (prevStock <> currentStock) or (prevStock is null)
) as t2
```